# Call a class to stop/pause slideshow on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, mootools, slideshow

I am adding some new code to [this](https://github.com/jakobholmelund/mootools-spin) Mootools slideshow.

I added thumbnails and a mouseover function that scrolls thru the thumbnails.
Now I need to make the timer on the slideshow stop/pause when `mouseenter`. I ma trying with the code under but got a `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method '_stopClock'`.

```
spinAreaDiv.addEvent('mouseenter', function(){
this._stopClock();  
})
```

How can I call the class `_stopClock`?

```
var Spin = new Class({
...
...
_stopClock:function(){
    if(!this.options.timer) { 
        return false; 
    } else {
        this.timerRunning = false;
        clearInterval(this.clock);
        this.timer.pause.addClass('active');
    }
},
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a binding issue. when an event callback from a dom event fires, this will be the element.

```
element.addEvent('something', function(){
    this === element; // true;
});

// save a reference
var self = this;
element.addEvent('something', function(){
    this === element; // true;
    self._stockClock(); // works.
});

// or. use Function.prototype.bind
element.addEvent('something', function(){
    this !== element; // true;
    this._stopClock(); // works.
}.bind(this));

// or even...
this.element.addEvent('something', this._stopClock.bind(this)); // works.
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem. I believe your answer is correct. (+1 for giving me 3 different ways to fix it). I have to read about "binding" to understand your answer. Will be back after that :)

Comment: By the way, tried your ideas, got `Object [object global] has no method '_stopClock'`. I think the problem is on my code. Will (as said) read more and will come back. Thanks!

Comment: I managed to make it work with your suggestion. I am still "green" in JS so I 'm not sure why the same code does not work inside a class who is inside a function. But I will check. Anyway, your answer made it work. Thanks!

Comment: i thought this was in the context of a class. normally when you extend stuff it is on the proto. `this.methodname` refers to a method on an object (class instance). if it goes to global object, you are extending the class wrong.